# How do I check if a graph is not a tree?

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree

How do I check if a given `undirected graph` is a `tree` or not? Is there any correlation between the two?

I thought of checking if the graph is connected or not? But is it sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for undirected graph to be a tree u have to check for 2 conditions.

1) The graph has to be connected.

2) There has to be no cycle.

DFS/BFS can be used to check both cases.